# What is the *.vshost.exe.config file?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, config

When I compile an application with VS2008 I sometimes end up with 2 identical config files:

- *.exe.config
- *.vshost.exe.config

What is the latter one for?

Comment: Thanks for the question to stir discussion.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here's a blog post that talks about the vshost process and its purpose.

http://blogs.msdn.com/dtemp/archive/2004/08/17/215764.aspx

Comment: Apart from the external link, you should add at least a little explanation, so that the answer is contained in SO and doesn't fully depend on an external resource that could dissapear.

Comment: This link is totally disappear now.

Comment: Do .NET Core apps use this?  Can they use launchSettings.json instead?

Answer (score 17):

When debugging inside VS your application will be called [appname].vshost.exe and so the .vshost.exe.config file is where the .net runtime will look for the program's config.

Comment: what happens if it is published to the server? Does it cause any problem?

Answer (score 2):

I noticed something else about this behaviour.

Whilst VS WILL create a config called [appname].vshost.exe.config, the API call:

```
var s = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile
```

does not return this name, rather it returns: [appname].config

This was using VS2010. Not checked in VS2008

Comment: I think its because if you have VS hosting enabled in the project properties debug tab it will be looking for [appname].vshost.exe.config. But if you have it disabled it will be looking for [appname].config. I migrated a project from VS2008 -> VS2013 and it would not read the config file no matter what it would return null. & the vshost.exe.config would never generate. So I had to turn off VS hosting described above, then rename app.config to [appname].config & put it in the bin folder. Now it works.

Answer (score 2):

This file's sole purpose is to help debugging and hosting Process.Visual Studio hosting process improves debugger performance. It enables new debugger features, such as partial-trust debugging and design-time expression evaluation.

If you disable the hosting process, partial-trust debugging will not work even if partial-trust security is enabled on the Security page of Project Properties.

You can disable that by  Project menu -> click Properties -> Debug tab -> Clear the Enable the Visual Studio hosting process check box. Design-time expression always uses the hosting process. Disabling the hosting process in the Project Properties disables design-time expression evaluation for Class Library projects.

For other project types, design-time expression evaluation is not disabled. Instead, Visual Studio starts the actual executable and uses it for design-time evaluation without the hosting process.